# Merging multiple selects together inside a table - Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have several select queries and want to merge them using their organization name.

Queries are as follow:

```
select ORG_ALL_SCORES.Name, ORG_ALL_SCORES.ALL_SCORES, SUM(REWARD_CONVERSION_FORMULA.FROM_REWARD_VALUE) AS Pasmaand FROM ORG_ALL_SCORES LEFT JOIN REWARDS_LIST ON REWARDS_LIST.ORGANIZATION_ID = ORG_ALL_SCORES.ORGANIZATION_ID
INNER JOIN REWARD_CONVERSION_FORMULA ON REWARD_CONVERSION_FORMULA.TO_REWARDS_LIST_ID = REWARDS_LIST.REWARDS_LIST_ID WHERE REWARD_CONVERSION_FORMULA.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%700022%' GROUP BY ORG_ALL_SCORES.NAME, ORG_ALL_SCORES.ALL_SCORES;
```

.

```
select ORG_ALL_SCORES.Name, ORG_ALL_SCORES.ALL_SCORES, SUM(REWARD_CONVERSION_FORMULA.FROM_REWARD_VALUE) AS Hamlonaghl FROM ORG_ALL_SCORES LEFT JOIN REWARDS_LIST ON REWARDS_LIST.ORGANIZATION_ID
= ORG_ALL_SCORES.ORGANIZATION_ID INNER JOIN REWARD_CONVERSION_FORMULA ON REWARD_CONVERSION_FORMULA.TO_REWARDS_LIST_ID = REWARDS_LIST.REWARDS_LIST_ID WHERE REWARD_CONVERSION_FORMULA.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%700041%' GROUP BY ORG_ALL_SCORES.NAME, ORG_ALL_SCORES.ALL_SCORES;
```

.

```
select ORG_ALL_SCORES.Name, ORG_ALL_SCORES.ALL_SCORES, SUM(REWARD_CONVERSION_FORMULA.FROM_REWARD_VALUE) AS Shahrvand FROM ORG_ALL_SCORES LEFT JOIN REWARDS_LIST ON REWARDS_LIST.ORGANIZATION_ID = ORG_ALL_SCORES.ORGANIZATION_ID
INNER JOIN REWARD_CONVERSION_FORMULA ON REWARD_CONVERSION_FORMULA.TO_REWARDS_LIST_ID = REWARDS_LIST.REWARDS_LIST_ID WHERE REWARD_CONVERSION_FORMULA.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%700061%' GROUP BY ORG_ALL_SCORES.NAME, ORG_ALL_SCORES.ALL_SCORES;
```

.

Now I want to have something like this:

[image]

.

But I have these results separately for each query:

[image]

and

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: If you did manage to join two tables to obtain some result, what stops you from joining more tables in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pivot function (if supported by the DB) or case statements with aggregation to achieve the result that you are looking for in a single query. For example -

```
SELECT o.Name, o.ALL_SCORES, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN rcf.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%700061%' then rcf.FROM_REWARD_VALUE else 0 END) AS Shahrvand,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rcf.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%700041%' then rcf.FROM_REWARD_VALUE else 0 END) AS Hamlonaghl,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rcf.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%700022%' then rcf.FROM_REWARD_VALUE else 0 END) AS Pasmaand
FROM ORG_ALL_SCORES o
INNER JOIN REWARDS_LIST rl ON o.ORGANIZATION_ID = rl.ORGANIZATION_ID
INNER JOIN REWARD_CONVERSION_FORMULA rcf ON rl.REWARDS_LIST_ID  = rcf.TO_REWARDS_LIST_ID 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(rcf.DESCRIPTION, '700061|700041|700022') 
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Alternately there are a myriad other ways of merging the results as post processing while continuing to use separate queries. For example, by using pandas data frames or ETL tools such as Talend. Talend provides a tMap component which helps you to easily achieve the result that you are looking for.